# Is there any difference between a Blue Steel Battle-Scarred and Factory New?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I'm wondering if there is a difference between different states of Blue Steel skin knifes ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the obvious cost factor, there are some cosmetic differences.

#### Battle Scared

http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/1839/Flip-Knife-Blue-Steel-Battle-Scarred

**Ingame view:**

[image]

#### Factory New

http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/id/1876/Flip-Knife-Blue-Steel-Factory-New

**Ingame view:**

[image]

Images from: http://csgo.steamanalyst.com/

Comment: These two aspects looks nice, and a difference is observable, but I mean, in game ? I can't find comparisons with same graphical settings on YouTube.
I've already had some Blue Steel (MW), and it has really nice light effects, but I don't know if I can get the same on a BS

Comment: You can always find it in the marketplace and inspect in game.

Comment: I know, but I can't see the reflects like in game when you press F key, it isn't the same :/

Comment: @HugoTor I've added some videos that shows ingame view.

Comment: Ok thanks ! Seems to be the same settings, perfect :D